# Finding the max on collection of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I find the max cell value in a collection of objects using lodash while ignoring one of the keys.

```
var data = [{
            tick: 0,
            valueA: 3,
            valueB: 2
        }, {
            tick: 6,
            valueA: 6,
            valueB: 3
        }, {
            tick: 12,
            valueA: 2,
            valueB: 4
        }, ...];
```

I want to find the max tick, this is the row identifier, and the max of all *other* values. What I have so far is:

```
var maxTick = _.max(data, 'tick'),
    maxValue = _.max(data, function(o) { return _.max(_.values(o))};);
```

How can I let `maxValue` ignore the tick data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using _.pick() to pick out all keys except tick then run your max function on that new collection.  By the way, your maxValue function doesn't seem right.  Are you saying that you want to take the highest scalar valuer in any object, or the object which contains the highest scalar value (except tick)?

UPDATE: Based on your response, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/Xxf9E/1/

```
var data = [{
            tick: 0,
            valueA: 3,
            valueB: 2
        }, {
            tick: 6,
            valueA: 6,
            valueB: 3
        }, {
            tick: 12,
            valueA: 2,
            valueB: 4
        }],
    data2 = [];

_.each(data, function(element, index) {
    var values = _.values(_.omit(element, 'tick'));
    data2 = data2.concat(values);
});

console.log(data2);
console.log(_.max(data2));
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. I think it is correct; I want to find the highest scaler value in any object.

Comment: this function will iterate though all objects twice and that's not performance wise if the data set is large.

Comment: @DeniMf: The question was to how to solve the problem using lodash.  Obviously, you can achieve some optimizations if you write custom code but it's up to the developer to gauge if the dataset is large enough to warrant such optimizations.

Comment: I prefer using clean JavaScript as much as possible and extending existing libraries instead of calling couple functions to achieve the same result.

Comment: This solution does double iteration through the whole collection and is not optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Along T Nguyen's line of thought but use `_.omit` instead of pick that way you only have to omit `tick`

```
_.max(data, function(o){_.omit(o, "tick")})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `_.omit`. T Nguyen was a bit faster with a full solution though so I have accepted his. Your code also has some bugs in it.

Comment: @Annan no problems I just wanted to get an answer out there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a function which iterates through all elements properties and a list of ignored properties. 
Here is a sample:

```
var  findMax = function(list, ignoredFields){
    var maxValue = null;
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        for(var prop in list[i]){
            if(ignoredFields.indexOf(prop) < 0){
                maxValue = maxValue < list[i][prop] ? list[i][prop] : maxValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

And you execute the function with your data and the list of ignored properties

```
findMax(data,['tick'])
```

Update: modified the function to use lodash iterations

```
var  findMax = function(list, ignoredFields){
    var maxValue = null;
    _.forEach(list, function(element, index) {
        var _localMax = _.max(_.omit(element, ignoredFields));
        maxValue = maxValue < _localMax ? _localMax : maxValue;
    });
    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: Your solution will be useful to people who read this as it is in pure javascript. However, my reason for using lodash is to follow a non-verbose functional coding style and therefore I cannot accept this as the answer.

Comment: just extend the lodash library with this function

Comment: First rule of open source libraries. If it does not have the functionality you want, extend it.